# Resistance measured individually vs measured on PCB

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, pcb, current, resistors

I always wanted to ask this question.

Suppose I have a 1 kΩ resistor. I measure its resistance by connecting a multimeter to both of its terminals (when it is not connected to any part of a circuit.) It reads 1 kΩ.

Then I connect this 1 kΩ resistor to a circuit present on a PCB. Assume an IC pin requires a 1 kΩ resistor connected to ground. In this case, when I measure the resistor across its terminals on the PCB, it reads a different value.

Can someone explain the reason behind this phenomenon?

Comment: As soon as you connect the resistor to something else with both terminals, you effectively have another resistance in parallel. So the total resistance you "see" on those terminals is different (smaller).

Comment: On PCB you are measuring cumulative or effective resistance across the terminals where the resistance is mounted. And the cumulative or effective resistance  will also vary based on the circuit where resistance is connected.

Comment: If it's an IC connected across your resistor, so probably diodes and transistors causing the shunting problem, then you may be able to make a meaningful reading if you measure resistance with a low voltage, <<700 mV so that the IC draws insignificant current. Few (no?) DMMs have this feature, so you'd have to build something. Ideally you'd measure at 50 mV, 100 mV and so on up to 500 mV, and draw a graph. If the graph has a linear region at low voltage, then that's the result, unless of course it's a linear resistance between the pins inside the IC!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multimeters don't measure resistance directly. They measure resistance by applying some test voltage, and measuring how much current flows, or by applying some test current and measuring how much voltage difference it causes. So the resistance the show on screen is calculated based on the other measurements.

If you only connect the resistor by itself, then there will only be the current through the resistor or voltage over the resistor that the multimeter measures.

If you try to measure the resistor in circuit, there will be other current paths in addition to the resistor, so as currents flow via other paths as well, so the assumption that all the current flows through the resistor is no longer true and the resistance cannot be calculated from measured voltage and current.

Depending on the other circuitry in parallel with the resistor, whether it consumes extra current from multimeter, or provides extra current to the multimeter, the calculated resistance value can be lower or higher that the actual resistance.

Answer (score 4):

ICs and other components aren't just plastic boxes with metal pins stuck in them.  They are full of electronic components - mostly transistors, but also diodes, resistors, capacitors, etc.

When you measure the resistance of a resistor on a PCB, you aren't measuring just that resistor.  You are also measuring the resistance of many of the other components in parallel with that resistor.

Take the good old [555 timer.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf)

[image]

There are three resistors connected in series between pins 8 (VCC) and 1 (ground.)  There's more in parallel with that, of course, but if you measure between pins 8 and 1 you'd expect to see no more than 15k - the sum of R3, R4, and R5.  It'll probably be less because there are other things in parallel with them.

Now imagine you connect your 1k resistor across pins 8 and 1 and measure it.

You'll find the resistance to be less than about 940 ohms.  A resistance of 1k in parallel with 15k works out to about 937.5 ohms.

---

In reality, things are more complicated.  If you really need to check the value of a part, take it off the PCB.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you measure a resistor you are also measuring the parallel resistance. It happens that when that parallel resistance is about 5mm of air, it is exceptionally high (infinite for practical purposes, at least until you cause an arc).

If you measure a higher resistor, say 1 megohm and hold the probes on with your fingers, you will measure something a bit lower because of the resistance of your body (yes, the multimeter is passing a tiny electrical current through you at this point).

If you measure on a board, it is no different. The resistor is connected to other things, and they usually have some parallel resistance.

If you are fault finding, what you can say is that you should measure NOT MORE than 1k, for a 1k resistor. The parallel circuit can only lower the resistance you measure - at least if there are no volts on the board.